# Why I cannot scan the character?

Tags: c, scanf

I try to scan character into the 2D array after I have scanned int before the loop. But it seems I cannot scan any character. Why is this happening?

```c
#include <stdio.h> 
int main() {
    int S_m, S_t, S_v, S_d;
    char dp[500][500];
    char nucleotide;
    int i, m;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &S_m, &S_t, &S_v, &S_d);
    for (i = 0; i < 500; i++){
         scanf("%c", &nucleotide);
         if (nucleotide == '\n'){
             m = i + 1;
             break;
         }
         dp[i+1][0] = nucleotide;
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= m; i++){
        printf("%c", dp[i+1][0]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Your code can scan some characters](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6UvkFpEPltBPuqs8).

Comment: Always check the value returned by scanf.  How do you know it's not matching if you don't check the return value?  You can't have any pudding if you don't eat yer meat.

Comment: "I cannot scan any character" What makes you think so?

Comment: You can. The character is whatever you typed after the 4th number. Probably the enter key.

Answer (score 3):

My guessing is you are putting a newline character after entering 4 numbers.

The newline character isn't consumed by

```
scanf("%d %d %d %d", &S_m, &S_t, &S_v, &S_d);
```

and is consumed by

```
scanf("%c", &nucleotide);
```

This makes the condition of the proceeding `if` statement true and exit from the loop without saving any characters to `dp`.

To avoid this kind of problem, you can use `fgets()` to read a line including a newline character and parse that via `sscanf()`.

```
char buffer[1024];
fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
sscanf(buffer, "%d %d %d %d", &S_m, &S_t, &S_v, &S_d);
```

Also note that the loop

```
for (i=0; i<=m; i++){
    printf("%c", dp[i+1][0]);
}
```

will print 2 NUL. You may want to rethink the value to set to `m` and the range of tlhe loop.

Comment: There's also the problem that `m` could still be uninitialized when that last loop is reached. And of course, the return values from `fgets`, `scanf` and `sscanf` should always be checked.

Answer (score 0):

This could work for you.

```c
scanf(" %c", &nucleotide);
```

Comment: This will prevent the condition `nucleotide == '\n'` from being true.

Comment: You could do this **one time before the loop**, and then `ungetc` the character that `scanf` returns. That would consume all of the whitespace between the last number and the first nucleotide, including the pesky newline that's causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the helping, I am scanning the character now yet a new problem appeared as I cannot leave the loop by break function as the condition nucleotide == '\n' seems to be always false now. What can I do?